# Fastest way to detect touchesmoved moves over an UIView?

Tags: swift, touch, multi-touch

I'm making a customkeyboard, it has almost 30 buttons.
And i'm using multi-touch event to check which button is being selected or touch over.
My way is detect current finger position and compare with button position.

But it seems too slow because i have to use for loop to check every single button coordinates.

Any faster way to check touchesmoved touches over 1 UIView or UIButton?

Answer (score 0):

For your keyboard buttons, you need to override the UIView method touchesBegan and touchesEnded. Touches began will be called when a touch enters the buttons frame, and touches ended will be called when a touch exits the buttons frame. No comparing of coordinates needed.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        //Button presses

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        //Button unpresses

    }
}
```

Note that there is a method known as touchesMoved which can be overriden in any UIView. This function is called any time touches move. You don't necessarily need to check any time a touch moves within the button, only when a touch begins and exits a button, so you shouldn't use the touchesMoved method in this case.

Comment: I've tried this way but it didn't work. Do you ever notice about iOS keyboard? If you touch on anywhere on the keyboard and move your finger, if your finger in the position of any button, you'll see the popup. To do it, i think i need to disable userInteractionEnabled in every button, and catch touchesmoved even in the keyboard.

Comment: Maybe, and if that doesn't work try disabling user interaction but doing the method I proposed... I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.